# emitting pyqtgraph.GraphicsScene.mouseEvents.mouseDragEvent

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I am trying to emit a signal which contains an object of the type pyqtgraph.GraphicsScene.mouseEvents.mouseDragEvent but I can't find a way to describe it in the constructor of the signal.

```
sigDragged = qtc.pyqtSignal(int, pg.Point, pg.GraphicsScene.mouseEvents.mouseDragEvent)
```

(qtc refers to PyQt5Core, and pg refers to pyqtgraph)

Attempting to use this code results in an error since pg.GraphicsScene refers to a class, not the file which contains mouseEvents. I've tried looking through the pyqtgraph __init__ to find where mouseDragEvent is imported, but it doesn't seem to be imported anywhere. Does this mean I can't refer to the class or create a signal with it? I have also tried to use PyQtGui.QMouseEvent but it just raises Unexpected Type since they aren't the same.

Comment: You can declare a generic `object` signature, but note that emitting a signal *with* an event (even if it's artificially created) is a strange requirement. Can I ask you what you're trying to achieve and why do you need to emit a signal with a pyqtgraph event?

Comment: I want a system where dragging from one ROI object to another ROI object causes a line to be drawn between the 2 objects. So I was passing the event into sigDragged in order for the handler to be able to check isStart() and isFinish(). I could make separate signals for those cases, or emit the return values of those functions within sigDragged but I thought this seemed better.

Comment: Considering that you will have to check those anyway, it would be simpler to just emit the signal with parameters that already have checked that; you could simplify it to a single argument with a simple integer value (for instance: 1 if `isStart()`, -1 is `isFinish()`, 0 for all other cases) or a bit mask (1 for start, 2 for finish - I don't know if it's possible to have an event that is both start *and* finish, but if it is, with that you can set both).

Comment: @musicamante Yeah i was thinking that, but it felt like it would decrease readability to have the if <var> == -1 elif == 0 elif == 1, but I guess with comments it wouldn't be so bad.

Comment: Nothing stops you to create your custom global constants (for instance, `StartDrag, Drag, EndDrag = -1, 0, 1`), so you don't have to rely on comments and your code will be much more readable both for signal creation *and* value comparison.

Comment: @musicmante That's true, thanks for your help. Though when using this as a module might it be a bit confusing to have random constants in the module's namespace?

Comment: If you properly use imports and choose appropriate names, that won't be an issue. It's common to have modules that only declare constants, so having a couple of further names that can ease up your code is certainly not a problem.